# expected value of maximum function.

Tags: probability

Suppose a fair coin is tossed four times. Let X be the number of heads obtained.
Comute the expected value of max{X, n − X}.

Actually I cannot understand what the problems means.

can you help me to know what is max{X, n − X}?

Comment: what is $n$? Is $n = 4$?

Comment: $X$ is the number of heads.  $n-X$ is presumably the number of tails.  $\max\{X, n − X\}$ is the higher of the two numbers.

Comment: It makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

Let $c_i \in \{0,1\}$ represent the result of the $i$th coin toss, if $c_i = 1$ then the toss was a head, tails otherwise.

That is, any experiment results in some $c_1,...,c_4$. Then $X(c) = c_1+c_2+c_3+c_4$, and $n-X(c) = 4-X(c) = 4-(c_1+c_2+c_3+c_4)$.

Then $M(c) = \max(X(c), 4-X(c)) = \max(c_1+c_2+c_3+c_4, 4-(c_1+c_2+c_3+c_4))$.

There are 16 possibilities for $c$, all equally likely. Hence the expected value is $E M = \frac{1}{16} \sum_{c \in \{0,1\}^4} \max(c_1+c_2+c_3+c_4, 4-(c_1+c_2+c_3+c_4))$.

It is easier to compute by gathering the outcomes together by number of heads obtained.

\begin{array}{ccc}
X & M & \text{number of outcomes of value }X \\
\hline \\
0 & 4 & \binom{4}{0} = 1\\
1 & 3 & \binom{4}{1} = 4 \\
2 & 2 & \binom{4}{2} = 6\\
3 & 3 & \binom{4}{3} =4 \\
4 & 4 & \binom{4}{4} =1\\
\end{array}

We obtain $E M = \frac{1}{16} (4 \cdot (1+1) + 3 \cdot (4+4) + 2 \cdot (6)) = \frac{11}{4}$.